# tail: cannot open ‘+2’ for reading: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to print the content of the file(myfile) from the line no 2 to line no 5 through the script.sh. The script is not able to open the file from the position 2.And also contents are printing from the 1st line to 4th line.Below are the file contents, command and the output of the command.

```
$cat myfile
SR.N0.  Details
Name    XXXX
DOB     XXXX
DOJ     xxxx
JOB     XXXX
DOMAIN  XXXX
COMPANY XXXX


$cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
tail +$1 $3 | head -n$2

$./script.sh 2 6 myfile
tail: cannot open ‘+2’ for reading: No such file or directory
==> myfile <==
SR.N0.  Details
Name    XXXX
DOB XXXX
DOJ xxxx
JOB XXXX
```

Comment: What OS, version of tail are you using?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 12.14

Comment: See: `man tail`

Comment: If you want to print lines 2 through 5, use `sed -n 2,5p`.  Piping tail to head is a common approach, but not the best.  `sed` is your friend here.

Comment: Please consider selecting the answer.

Answer (score 12):

`tail` accepts the line count as part of the `-n ...` or `--lines=...` flag. From the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html):

> ```
>    -n, --lines=[+]NUM
>           output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n
>           +NUM to output starting with line NUM
> ```

Replace `tail +$1 $3` with `tail -n +$1 $3` or `tail --lines=+$1 $3`.

As an interesting note, you are already using using the correct flag for `head`.

There is also a very similar question on Server Fault: https://serverfault.com/questions/133692/how-to-display-certain-lines-from-a-text-file-in-linux. The general consensus there is that your method is fine, but an alternative may be to write `script.sh` using `sed` as something like

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -n "${1},${2}p" ${3}
```